# WCF response time reduction

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap, asmx

I had a 3rd party webservice. When i hit that using Soap UI respose time is just 800 milliseconds. But when i am running it through code 
e.g

```
stopWatch.Start();
WCFSERV.ServiceCommitment[] service_commitments = new WCFSERV.Service().GetServiceCommitments(mailProperties);
stopWatch.Stop();

// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
label1.Text= stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
```

It's coming to be 24 seconds. What am i doing wrong here? how can we improve the performance?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your traffic (using Fiddler or similar) to see if there's a difference between the requests?

Comment: Make sure it is not dns resolve issue (use ip address instead of domain url) and you are not using SSL in WCF and not in Soap UI.

Comment: I am using asmx service, and consuming it from console just a test app. In SOAP UI also i am using the same URL(domain url).